# Invert the association of yaml nodes in terraform

Tags: terraform

Assuming the following `yaml` input file

```yaml
admins:
  members:
    - john@gmail.com
    - peter@gmail.com
viewers:
  members:
    - maria@gmail.com
    - john@gmail.com
```

that is passed to `var.memberships` via `yamldecode`, is it possible to produce a list of objects that has the `member` as `key` and the groups it belongs to as values, i.e. something like

```
{
  "maria@gmail.com" = {
    groups = ["viewers"]
  },
  "john@gmail.com" = {
    groups = ["admins", "viewers"]
  },
  "peter@gmail.com" = {
    groups = ["admins"]
  }
}
```

Comment: In a declarative language this would normally require returning appended lists from a lambda/closure `for` expression (analogous to the algorithm in Puppet) because a `member` can belong to multiple `groups`, and I am unsure if Terraform supports RValue `for` expressions instead of only within constructors (similar to Python). There may be a clever solution here with the ellipsis operator (`...`) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer for projecting one data structure into another in the Terraform language is [`for` expressions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for).

In this particular case the [Grouping Results](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#grouping-results) mechanism would be a part of the solution, because you want to map potentially many elements from the input to a single element in the output by grouping by a particular key (the email addresses).

I think I'd start by first flattening out this data structure so that it's just a single set of member+group pairs where each element is therefore describing the relationship between one member and one group alone.

```
locals {
  memberships = setunion([
    for group_name, group in var.memberships : toset([
      for member_email in group.members : {
        member_email = member_email
        group_name   = group_name
      }
    ])
  ]...)
}
```

With this declaration and your example input I would expect the intermediate result to be:

```
memberships = toset([
  { member_email = "john@gmail.com", group_name = "admins" },
  { member_email = "peter@gmail.com", group_name = "admins" },
  { member_email = "maria@gmail.com", group_name = "viewers" },
  { member_email = "john@gmail.com", group_name = "viewers" },
])
```

We can then project this a second time to transform it into a map from email addresses to collections of groups:

```
locals {
  member_groups = tomap({
    for membership in local.memberships :
    membership.member_email => membership.group_name...
  })
}
```

```
member_groups = tomap({
  "john@gmail.com" = ["admins", "viewers"]
  "maria@gmail.com" = ["viewers"]
  "peter@gmail.com" = ["admins"]
})
```

This now has the same information as the data structure you wanted but not quite the right shape, so one more transformation can achieve exactly the map of objects you described in your question:

```
locals {
  users = tomap({
    for email, groups in local.member_groups : email => {
      groups = toset(groups)
    }
  })
}
```

```
users = tomap({
  "john@gmail.com" = {
    groups = toset(["admins", "viewers"])
  }
  "maria@gmail.com" = {
    groups = toset(["viewers"])
  }
  "peter@gmail.com" = {
    groups = toset(["admins"])
  }
})
```